# Can json data be sent to web service using GET request?

Tags: php, android, json, web-services, httpurlconnection

I want to send the `json` data which contains login information to the `webservice` using **GET** request. What I am doing right now is the following,

```
public JSONObject getJsonData(String url) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        JsonObject jsonSend = new JsonObject();
        jsonSend.addProperty("email","email@gmail.com");
        jsonSend.addProperty("password","*********");
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            URL url1 = new URL(url.toString());

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url1
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput (true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.connect();
            OutputStream out = null;
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(jsonSend.toString());
            Log.e("jsondata", jsonSend.toString());
            writer.close();
            out.close();
            conn.getResponseCode();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream());

            int b;
            while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
            try {
                Log.e("stringbuilder",stringBuilder.toString());
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error while creating json", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
//            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
```

Even though I am specifying request method as GET, it's trying to insert the data in the `webservice`. The `webservice` has the **php** code which will accept the `json` data and return a `json` data if the user credentials are valid and it accepts GET request. Please let me know how I can solve this. Thanks..

Comment: You can send in url as json string.

Comment: You can send in url, but this is bad idea. Better use POST

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. So there is no way to send the json data using GET other than passing it in the URL??

Comment: If you are using Retrofit, you could put your JSON info in the header and issue a get request in the normal way.

Comment: If you are sending login information to server then use `authorization` header. That is the best idea I guess.

Comment: Go through this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body/978094#978094

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant define the content type in the get() request type. So you cant send a json in get request. As you are able to sent headers in get request but in header you cant send the json file.